# Neo4j graph does not render correctly

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, neo4j-browser

Please see the attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tKWw.png). Both the nodes and the relationship are created using merge query such as below.

```
MERGE (e1:entity1{prop:'propvalue'}) 
MERGE (e2:entity2{prop:'propvalue'}) 
MERGE (e1)-[:rel]->(e2)
```

when I query as below, the graph shown is produced.

`MATCH (e1:entity1)-[:rel]-(e2:entity2{prop:'propvalue'}) RETURN e1, e2`

The arrows are all floating around and don't look well connected, what am I doing wrong? I'm a neophyte in Neo4j. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the problem must be with the browser or maybe it is not having sufficient display drivers to show the visualisations correctly. As I executed the quries the display was working fine. Which version are you using?

Comment: viewed on Firefox Quantum - 57.0.2 (64 bit); Neo4j - v3.2.2 community - do the queries sound okay to you -creation and retrieval?

Comment: did you try accessing it from other browsers?

Comment: Tried the queries on IE. again not looking good on there too.

Comment: The thing is it's a unidirectional relationship that I have created. Is that a problem?

Comment: you did give the direction `MERGE (e1)-[:rel]->(e2)`, And not giving direction in match is not a problem . Did you try on chrome?

Comment: In query, if I try the unidirection (e1-rel->e2), the results are good on Chrome. On other browsers that doesn't seem to make any difference. It's totally weird.

Comment: here's your answer then. Try using chrome. It supports graphics for neo4j well. I can say this because i've been using it from the start.

Comment: if you find it correct then accept the answer. ;)

Comment: Hey Shaik,I updated Neo4j to 3.3.1 and it seems to work fine on Firefox too. I have to still fix the Chrome on my laptop, so will keep you posted. Thanks so much for the suggestions.